# Product list slow (category and searchresult pages), what can i change/remove?

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm fighting with the product list view, it is loading too slow. 
When pages are cached, speed is OK (stupid to tell this, but maybe this info is needed ;-))

Mysql queries: +- 800 per category or new search request (I think this is that much because I have 190 000 products in my shop).
All settings are OK (what I can see with mysql tuner and other stuff like profiler).

I think the problem is somewhere in the attributes that needs to be loaded in the list.html. I have seen on other people posts there is a problem with `$attrs  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);` I cannot find where that code is located and if I need to change that file to get my custom attributes faster.

Is there a easy way to find the attribute or code that is slowing down `list.phtml`?

Maybe 1 file where I can remove stuff and recheck the load time after I removed stuff?

I have also tried to remove blocks in the local.xml but that was not fixing the load time.

I have changed the `"new product"` stamps, so it won't load `"new"` but my custom attribute (% a product is dropped, just a textfield no calculating with php just plain text).

I load that custom attribute and load different `"buy now"` buttons.

```
depending on a custom attribute, 
if (attribute = "ID") {
 then load this button 
}
if (attribute ID = 2) {
 load this button
}
```

So I just load 2 custom attributes, maybe attributes are not the problem. But it needs to be somewhere. The thing I know for sure is when I add more products the loading time will be longer.

Suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Aoe_Profiler](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_Profiler) or the default profiler (Nice article about that on [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/keeping-your-magento-fit-with-built-in-profiler/)) to analyse whats happening on your page. It might very well be an issue in your template.

Also make sure the attributes you want to use in the `list.phtml` are added to the flat product index. You can do this on the attribute edit page.
[image]

And turn on flat category and product indexes on `System > Configuration > Catalog`. This will definitely speed up your list page when caching is not turned on.

Comment: Profiler: done that, problem is in sql. After 1st request there is a delay.

Comment: Profiler: done that, problem is in sql. After 1st request there is a delay in sql. SQL is telling me to much JOINS and some stuff not using indexes. You are talking about indexes with your image. All the attributes that needs to be loaded in list view are set to "yes" in product listing. Do i need to check every other attribute and set it on "no"? I have logged my queries (slow) but i don't see long queries 0.003 is not slow or is it? I already use flat categories and products. I found that using flat will bypass EAV stuff but why do i still see INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table`

Comment: i have checked a bunch attributes. Like color, description, color, cost, short-description, news_from_date They all have "yes" for "used in production listing" but i don't use/show those attributes in product list. Problem found? I cannot remember i have set those attributes to "yes". Will try to set attributes i won't show in the list view. will report back.

Comment: no effect. i still got over 800 mysql queries, this can't be normal :(

Comment: Install a clean version of Magento to compare whats normal. This way you can track down the issue more accurate because we can be fairly sure it's something custom build/added :)

Comment: My vps provider switches hosts or something, my server down so i freaked-out. Server back online, now i have 50% less requests. But also my loading times for pages are 200% higher. No support from vps provider. I think i will go sell my webshop, i'm done with this stuff. I pay more and more and the problems are just getting bigger and more.

Comment: Too bad to hear that. Maybe sit down with a company that can provide you with Magento development. Initial costs will be higher but not having to spend your time on it and a better webshop will compensate for that

Comment: yeah, maybe a restart with a other company. I was so happy yesterday. I got my loading times for cached and no cached pages so low.... <1sec. for cached and 3-4sec. for non cached cat/search pages. Now 2-3sec. for cached and 15-20 for non-cached pages. I have changed nothing and site was ok for 10hours or so, vps provider did his thing and i'm . yeah not so happy. Problem is i already fighting with magento for months, sales are dropped to zero. My money is at the vps company and magento extension sellers. I can let look the vps company for solving the problems they started for $110,- per hour.

Comment: 'Your website is faster than 92% of all tested websites' >;-) My speed is back. I think i fixed it (i lowered innodb_thread_concurrency and thread_concurrency with 30% and innodb_buffer_pool_size with 50%, i restarted mysqld but saw now changes.) Just hours later my speed was back. Maybe the VPS company found the handbreak or i fixed it. Fingers crossed, let's see what it does the next 24hours. Now i don't dare to reindex or clear caches ;-)

Comment: i hope the last update: i lowered read_rnd_buffer_size and join_buffer_size both to 4MB. Now my insane high requests are back 800+ per non cached category page, but my page loading time have been dropped again (a small bit, but now it is 839ms for cached and 2.30s for non cached cat. pages +- 5 sec. for new search results much lower after the search (collection cache i think?)). me = happy

Comment: Put all these comments in an answer. the info might be useful for future readers!